# Gegenteil von "laut lesen"

Tags: antonym

Was ist das Gegenteil von "laut lesen", also wenn man etwas für sich liest? Und wie lautet das entsprechende Imperativ, die Forderung, aufzuhören, beim Lesen nicht mitzusprechen?

Comment: Laut lesen ist aber nicht nachsprechen, sondern mitsprechen.

Comment: Welcher Imperativ ist gesucht? "Lies laut" oder "lies leise"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Stilles Lesen

Beim Lesen wird als Gegensatz zum *lauten* Lesen häufig vom *stillen* Lesen gesprochen.

> **Stilles** Lesen wird daher erst spannend, wenn die Vorlesegeschwindigkeit zumindest erreicht oder noch überboten wird. Nur etwa 50 Prozent der Schüler des sechsten Schuljahres nehmen diese wichtige Hürde. <sup>[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesen)</sup>
>
> **Stilles Lesen** gewinnt in der Grundschule auch in den ersten Klassen immer mehr an Bedeutung. Anstatt einen Text gleich laut vorlesen zu lassen, geben die Lehrer den Schülern zunächst Zeit, sich still damit zu befassen. <sup>[Focus](http://www.focus.de/familie/wissenstest/lernatlas/ruhe-ich-will-lesen-klasse-3-4_id_2175148.html)</sup>
>
> Das **stille Lesen** ist die im Leben vorherrschende und geforderte Leseform. Deshalb sollte es auch im Unterricht gepflegt werden – am besten mit Texten, die die Schüler/innen selbst auswählen. <sup>[Antolin](https://www.antolin.de/nl/nl_06_09_sept/nl_06_09_sept_stilles_lesen.jsp)</sup>

Der Imperativ wäre demnach:

> Lies bitte still!

Answer (score 6):

Das Gegenteil von *laut* ist *leise*, also ist das Gegenteil von *laut lesen* einfach *leise lesen*.

Von daher ist der Imperativ auch: Lies leise!

Comment: In diesem Zusammenhang würde ich aber stumm bevorzugen.

Comment: Ich stimme zu, dass "Lies bitte leise!" eine gute Möglichkeit ist es auszudrücken und eine die ich verwenden würde wenn ich je in die Situation käme. Daneben ist vielleicht auch das häßliche Verb "subvokalisieren" hier zu nennen, es beschreibt das innere Mitlesen mit deiner "inneren Stimme". Wichtig hier ist das dass subvokalisieren nicht nötig ist um leise zu lesen.

Comment: Der OP fragt nach dem Imperativ, laut zu lesen.

Comment: @IQV Er fragt nach der "Forderung […] beim Lesen nicht mitzusprechen", was nach meinem Verständnis eben auf "Lies leise/Lies still" hinaus läuft.

Comment: Er fragt nach der Forderung "aufzuhören, nicht mitzusprechen".

Comment: Die Frage wurde vor kurzem geändert. Die ursprüngliche Formulierung war: "Forderung aufzuhören das Gelesene nachzusprechen". Und darauf bezieht sich (wohl nicht nur) meine Antwort.

Comment: Das ist richtig. Die erste (zwischenzeitlich editierte) Version der Frage hatte ich nicht gesehen.

Answer (score 1):

Für stummes Lesen gibt es kein eigenes Verb, vermutlich, weil es Standard ist.

> lesen = stumm lesen
>
> laut lesen / vorlesen = beim Lesen sprechen

Es gibt aber diese Erweiterungskonstruktion:

> Lies bitte für dich! / Bitte für dich lesen!

Ansonsten kann die Aufforderung, stumm zu lesen, nur eine Aufforderung sein, den Mund zu halten.

> [Halt die] Schnauze!
>   *(derbes Beispiel)*

Comment: Evtl *still* statt *stumm*?

Comment: @Takkat: Recht hat er, _»stilles Lesen«_ ist gebräuchlicher als _»stummes Lesen«_, ist mir jetzt aber nicht _so_ wichtig, dass ich die Antwort anpasse, müsstest du dann selber machen. Immerhin heißt es statt _»Stillschaltung«_ _»Stummschaltung«_ – Habe gerade bemerkt, dass ein wichtiger Teil meiner Antwort schon in der Frage steht, peinlich.

Comment: Der OP fragt nach dem Imperativ, laut zu lesen.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn man jemanden auffordern möchte, beim Lesen nicht mitzusprechen, kann man auch sagen:

> Lies das bitte im Stillen!

Comment: Der OP fragt nach dem Imperativ, laut zu lesen.

Comment: Die Frage des OP ist ein bisschen unklar formuliert. Ich finde aber, es liegt näher, herauszulesen, dass er eine Imperativform für "leise lesen" (o.ä.) sucht.

Comment: Das ist richtig. Die Formulierung ist so eine Art "doppelte Verneinung" und nur schwer zu verstehen.